# How can I express "my cold is usually cured automatically without medicine in 1 day" properly?

Tags: expressions

As the title says, I guess the original expression is not proper, I hope to know how native English speakers will express. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say something like:

> My cold usually *cures itself* in 1 day